# The following matrix has determinant 1, can anyone prove it?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

For $n\in \mathbb{N}$, define the $n\times n$ matrix $A^{(n)}$ by
$$ A^{(n)}_{ij} = \frac{(i-1)^{(j-1)}}{(j-1)!}, \quad 1\leq i,j\leq n$$
with the convention $0^0=1$. I believe $\text{det}(A^{(n)})=1$ for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$, but I can't seem to prove it. I have verified computationally that it holds. So far induction has not gotten me anywhere. Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: Hint: just expand this completely and find a combinatoric interpretation.

Comment: $A=\pmatrix{1&0\\ \mathbf 1&V_{n-1}}\operatorname{diag}\left(1,\frac{1}{1!},\cdots,\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\right)$ where $V_{n-1}$ is a Vandermonde matrix.

Comment: Alternatively, note you have $\det(f_j(x_i))$ with each $f_j(x)$ being $\binom{x}{j-1}$ plus linear combination of $f_{j-1}(x),\dots,f_1(x)$.  But $(\binom{i-1}{j-1})$ is obviously unipotent lower triangular.